# get URL links from xml in as3 and set to each button in my timeline

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, hyperlink

Right now I have a static way that I set the url's to 5 buttons, here's a sample of what I am doing:

```
Object(root).grid_slider.links.twitter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToTwitter);
Object(root).grid_slider.links.facebook.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToFacebook);


function fl_ClickToGoToFacebook(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.facebook.com"), "_blank");
}

function fl_ClickToGoToTwitter(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.twitter.com"), "_blank");
}
```

I'm kindof noob to flash I kinda gave up on it after Flash MX but now I was asked to make just a quick slider(which of course I recommened jquery but they wouldn't have it).  I have everything working fine but I have been asked that the url's are loaded from a xml file instead of static.  Not quite sure where to go from here..I've read how to read from xml but do I need to set the values in global variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MYXML>
    <FACEBOOK>"http://www.facebook.com"</FACEBOOK>
    <TWITTER>"http://www.twitter.com"</TWITTER>
</MYXML>
```

You load this xml to a myLinks variable:

```
var myLinks:XML;
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("link to your xml file");
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlLoader_completeHandler);
urlLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, urlLoader_securityErrorHandler);
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, urlLoader_ioErrorHandler);

function urlLoader_completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    myLinks = new XML(event.target.data);
}

function urlLoader_securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void
{
    // Do you have crossdomain.xml?
}

function urlLoader_ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    // Houston, we have a problem!
}

Object(root).grid_slider.links.twitter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToTwitter);
Object(root).grid_slider.links.facebook.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToFacebook);

function fl_ClickToGoToFacebook(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(myLinks.FACEBOOK.toString()), "_blank");
}

function fl_ClickToGoToTwitter(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(myLinks.TWITTER.toSting()), "_blank");
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at original_fla::Symbol2_15/fl_ClickToGoToFacebook()
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at original_fla::Symbol2_15/fl_ClickToGoToTwitter()
Is it not loading the xml?

Comment: You may add a trace function to the `urlLoader_completeHandler` method and see what you do get. Also it is possible that you call one of the `navigateToURL` methods before an XML file was loaded. I didn't add a trigger for this situation, but you should to do it.